# asp Identity 2.0 adding new roles and adding user to roles

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I'm having trouble understanding the new Identity stuff.  I'm trying to figure out how to add new roles and add user's to those roles.  I'm trying to create a role management page and a user management page for my application and need to be able to do those two things.  Everytime i try to add a role to a user like this:  System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("Andy", "admin");   I get "The Role Manager feature has not been enabled."  I don't have a custom role provider and i tried turning role manager to enabled but just got an error about not having a role provider.  I figured Identity had all this built in already?  Can somebody help me through this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`System.Web.Security` is the old ASP.NET Membership framework. ASP.NET Identity is in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. Use a `RoleManager` to create roles, and a `UserManager` to add users to roles.

```
using (var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context)) 
{
    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));
}

using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context)))
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin" };
    userManager.Create(user, "admin321");
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
}
```

Comment: UserManager and RoleManager implement IDisposable so that needs to be considered too.

Comment: where does  this piece of code go? Which class? I have no RoleManager.cs or UserManager.cs. TIA