# Asp.Net core MVC6 How to initially add roles in Identity 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I've looked for this in Stackoverflow and so far it appears there are plenty of questions on adding roles in Identity [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541101/add-role-in-asp-net-identity) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187028/asp-identity-2-0-adding-new-roles-and-adding-user-to-roles) but its different in Identity 3.

I want to seed roles in the database. I have just two.  I intended to use _roleManager which I have injected into the class. Thats fine. My problem is.. there doesnt appear to be any method to actually add a role.. Using CreateAsync is for adding the user to the role.. how do you code to add a role using "_userManager" or do you have to do it another way?

Comment: `_roleManager` is for creating roles and `_userManager` is for adding users to the roles. I've posted an answer to help

Comment: I have [a project here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe) that may interest you, it implements multi-tenant user and role management with identity 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Identity**

In **`Identity`** `RoleManager` is for creating roles and `UserManager` is for adding users to roles.
This is an example to point you in the right direction. The code below is for creating a new role `Administrator`

```
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            {
                MyIdentityRole newRole = new MyIdentityRole("Administrator", "Administrators can do something with data");
                roleManager.Create(newRole);
            }
```

**EDIT**

Further, this is for adding a user to a role and this also an example:

```
 \\assuming you test if the user has been assigned to the role "Administrator" before adding them to that role

 if(RoleAdministrator == true){
           userManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Administrator");
       }
```

Comment: I have been playing with this for the last hour or so and it appears in Identity 3, rolemanager does not have create... or any method that will create a role.. I counted 22 methods for roleManager...

Comment: Curious: why using a different approach with Identity 3? RoleManager still exists and is clearly the recommended approach to manage roles.

Comment: @si2030 roleManager should have the `create` Method. You can find it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613286(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: In Identity Core it'll be `createAsync`.  https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/RoleManager-TRole/index.html#methods

Comment: You don't need to check if role exists. It's part of the default model in `RoleValidator`.


`var newRole = new ApplicationRole
{
 Name = model.RoleName,
 Description = model.RoleDescription
};
var result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);
if (result.Succeeded) // do something
else // do something else - error will be in result.errors
{
 foreach (var error in result.Errors)
  // do something with error
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SeedData
{
    private const string _adminRoleName = "admin";
    private string _adminEmail = "admin@demo.com";
    private string _adminPassword = "P@ssw0rd!PK";

    private string[] _roles = new string[] { _adminRoleName, "supervisor" };

    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public  static async Task Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var serviceScope =serviceProvider
                                 .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                                 .CreateScope())
        {
            var instance = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SeedData>();
            await instance.Initialize();

            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
            if (!context.Products.Any())
            {
               // Seed Other entities Here
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    public SeedData(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                                  RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        foreach (var role in _roles)
        {
            if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<Guid>(role));
            }
        }

        var adminUsers = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(_adminRoleName);
        if (!adminUsers.Any())
        {
            var adminUser = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Email = _adminEmail,
                UserName = _adminEmail
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, _adminPassword);
            if(result.Success)
            {
               await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, _adminRoleName);
            }
       }         
   }
}
```

**In your Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var host = BuildWebHost(args);

     using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
     {
         var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
         try
         {
              SeedData.Run(services).Wait();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
             logger.LogError(ex, "Error while seeding database.");
         }
     }

      host.Run();
  }
```

Might be helpful to someone :)