# How to add Admin role ( My solution )

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0

I cannot find any working solution... I tried every google result. 
I am figthing with this for couple of hours.

So I just insert my new role to SQL tables with:

```
insert into [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ( [Id]
      ,[ConcurrencyStamp]
      ,[Name]
      ,[NormalizedName] )
values(1,NULL,'Admin','Admin') ;

Insert into [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (  [UserId]
      ,[RoleId] )
VALUES('user_id_from_[dbo].[AspNetUsers]' , 1 )
```

I think it is so ugly and really worst I can do, but it's working.

On SO is one answer marked as solution: 
[Asp.Net core MVC6 How to initially add roles in Identity 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807591/asp-net-core-mvc6-how-to-initially-add-roles-in-identity-3)

but I really have no idea after looking for answers in google how to properly initialize roleManager in Startup.cs.

I don't even believe it is really that hard. I think I just missing some clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually **Admin Roles** are seeded into the database while creating the schema. You are using Identity to create or seed the **Admin Role**. Identity uses Code-First approach so that you can customize it as much as possible. Don't use SQL queries manually. Below is way through which you can create an **Admin User** with Administrator privileges data at runtime using DI because EFCore does not yet support built-in support for Seeding data (It will support in the update).

To Seed Data, create a class (AdministratorSeedData.cs for example) in the **Data Folder** and add the following code.

```
public class AdministratorSeedData
{
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AdministratorSeedData(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task EnsureSeedDataAsync()
    {
        if (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("someone@someone.com") == null)
        {
            ApplicationUser administrator = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "someone@someone.com",
                Email = "someone@someone.com"
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(administrator, "Passw0rd123!");
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));

            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(administrator, "Administrator");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `Startup.cs` class, register this service in the DI container as:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.AddTransient<AdministratorSeedData>();
    }
```

and

```
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, AdministratorSeedData seeder)
    {
        ....
        await seeder.EnsureSeedDataAsync();
    }
```

Make sure that there is no database created. Run the application and you will see that the User with Administrator Role is created successfully.