# How to add custom roles to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807669/831138) but it doesn't seem to fit in my ASP Net Core project.

Things I am trying to understand:

- How can I add a custom role. I've even looked directly in my MySQL database (table `aspnetroles`), but I don't know what to use as `Id` and `ConcurrencyStamp`.
- Where do I put the code to seed the database with these new roles: in `Startup`? in `Register` under `AccountController`?
- How do I tie this new role to a user? I've even looked through the tables and I don't know how to assign the data (there is no `user2role` or `aspnetusers.role_id`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could do this easily by creating a `CreateRoles` method in your startup class. This helps check if the roles are created, and creates the roles if they aren't; on application startup.  Like so.

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //adding customs roles : Question 1
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Manager", "Member" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 2
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        //Here you could create a super user who will maintain the web app
        var poweruser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = Configuration["AppSettings:UserName"],
            Email = Configuration["AppSettings:UserEmail"],
        };

        string userPWD = Configuration["AppSettings:UserPassword"];
        var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration["AppSettings:AdminUserEmail"]);

       if(_user == null)
       {
            var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, userPWD);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                //here we tie the new user to the role : Question 3
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");

            }
       }
    }
```

and then you could call the `await CreateRoles(serviceProvider);` method from the `Configure` method in the Startup class. 
ensure you have `IServiceProvider` as a parameter in the `Configure` class.

Edit:
If you're using ASP.NET core 2.x, my article here provides a much detailed experience.
[here](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17333/Custom-user-roles-and-rolebased-authorization-in-ASPNET-core/28352#.WLQMoxIrKu4)

Comment: That looks like it! I'll try to implement it when I get home, I'll mark it as "answered" as soon as I test it in my code. About "Where do I put the code": I presume I should call it at the end of the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. Yes, you can call it at the end of the `Configure` method. Right after configuring routes.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. Marking it as answered. Just a quick note, since there were some steps that were not trivial for me (in case it can help someone else): in order to call your function from the bottom of the `Configure` method, I did it like so: `var serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceProvider>(); CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();`.

Comment: To call the function at the end of `Configure` method just do it like `CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();` but be sure that for parameter of `Configure` method to be `IServiceProvider serviceProvider`. For example: `Configure(/*other parameters*/, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)`.

Comment: @temilajumoke - your link is broken. 404.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Temi's detailed answer, remember to replace

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
```

With

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
```

Also, make sure that the types specified in `AddIdentity<>` is the same as the types called in `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<>`

For the above, our types called in `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<>` in Configure.cs would be

```
 var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
 var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

Another important thing to note is that since `CreateRoles(IServiceProvider)` (from Temi's answer) is an async method, to call it in `Configure` method (which return void), you can use
`CreateRoles(serviceProviderInstance).Wait();`
Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish I could have read this before struggling to solve the problems myself

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Temi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42204984) and [Xavier's comment to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188927/how-to-add-custom-roles-to-asp-net-core#comment71652977_42204984), my experience with this was a little different using [asp.net-core-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-2).

In order to get this working I had to add the `IServiceProvider` as a parameter of the `Configure` method to get an instance of it.

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder App,
    IHostingEnvironment Env,
    ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory,
    IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
)
{
    /* trimmed */

    CreateRoles(ServiceProvider).Wait();
}
```