# Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context error

Tags: postgresql

Hello I want to add role based authentication for my aspnetcore2.0 + postgresql project. for this reason I followed 
[How to create roles in asp.net core and assign them to users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users)

but I get error

Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context

by the way, I dont have identityrole and identityuser tables in my db table.

the simple project can be downloaded from http://eticaret.turkalpkucur.com/katmanliproje2.rar

Answer (score 0):

If your context its called DBContext maybe the namespace it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**

Added this and it worked:

`builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId })`;

**Option 2.**

The most common reasons for

The model name does not match with the table name in database
EntityFramework cannot figure out required meta by convention and you have not overriden it.
AppDbContext is NOT inherited from DbContext but instead it should be inherited from IdentityDbContext
In accountcontroller.cs and startup.cs model doest not match then this types of issue has been occured for example

```
    public class Role : IdentityRole
    {       
    }
```

in your DbContext.cs

```
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, IdentityUserRole<string>,
    IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
    {
        public DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
           : base(options)
        {
        } 
    }
```

in your startup.cs

```
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
```

In the given above, there is a different Role model so this is not working. You can change `startup.cs` call

replace

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
```

to

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, Role>()
```

because you have add `Role` class in your DataContext

**Option 3.**

Check that your `AppDbContext` is NOT inherited from `DbContext` but instead it should be inherited from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`