Why I cant add users to their respective roles the AspnetUserrole table?
I'm new to Asp.NET Core 7 MVC. I created a custom identity and roles and i want to assign roles to users during registration. However the roles are not being assigned to the respective users as my ASPNetUserRole table is empty. Below is the code. The users are being saved to the database table but they are not being assigned the roles.

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new()
                {
                    UserName = model.UserName,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Form = model.Form,
                    BirthDate = model.BirthDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
                };

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    // Assign the selected role to the user after creating the user
                    if (model.SelectedRoleId != null)
                    {
                        var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.SelectedRoleId);
                        if (role != null)
                        {
                            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }

            model.RoleList = await GetRoleSelectListAsync();
            return View(model);
        }

ASPNETUSERROLETABLE
ASPNETUser table
Any help or advice is appreciated

are you sure you have the necessary identity services configured in program.cs?  builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)     .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Yes I do @BryanDellinger
`builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
options =>
{
options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
}
)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();`


check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928655/aspnetuserroles-empty-after-usermanager-addtorolesasync-succeeds

So I figured the problem to my cause :
I was using FindByIdAsync(model.SelectedRoleId) in my register method while passing Value = role.Name in the GetRoleSelectListAsync()method.So i had to change FindByIdAsync to FindByNameAsync to solve the issue.
