# Authorize with roles and multiple authentication schemes per custom default policy not working for all schemes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-authorization

## Question

How do I make it so that tokens for both schemes work with roles regardless of whether a "Default" scheme token or a "Secondary" scheme token is used?

At the moment, either token will work (200 response) for any API that has `.RequireAuthorization()`, but only tokens belonging to the scheme identified by `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` will work for APIs that have `.RequireAuthorization(a => a.RequireRole(roleName));`.

Changing which scheme `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` points at changes which tokens work with APIs requiring the Administrator role, even though both tokens have this role, despite belonging to different schemes.

So what is the solution here?

## Reproduction case

### Code

This should be everything needed to reproduce the problem. The JWT tokens were generated using a testing service (Don't worry! There's no credential leaks here!).

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
 
namespace AuthorizeProblemSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string roleName = "Administrator";
            const string defaultScheme = "Default";
            const string secondaryScheme = "Secondary";
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = defaultScheme;
                o.DefaultScheme = defaultScheme;
            })

            // JWT credentials generated for this sample using Jamie Kurtz's JWT Builder.
            // No credentials have been harmed in the making of this sample.

            // Default scheme token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUyODkzMjMsImV4cCI6MTcyNjgyNTMyMywiYXVkIjoiZGVmYXVsdEF1ZGllbmNlIiwic3ViIjoidXNlcjFAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20ifQ.SH3mxkdJCjdQ4HUX7sRPLJ2_7baW2OwNhB39fnGduD8
            .AddJwtBearer(defaultScheme, o => o.Audience = "defaultAudience")
            // Secondary scheme token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUyODkzMjMsImV4cCI6MTcyNjgyNTMyMywiYXVkIjoic2Vjb25kYXJ5QXVkaWVuY2UiLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyMUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSJ9.TNamLBog9qxLiebI7F8hu0dX09MjZlGoydKYeDve0ig
            .AddJwtBearer(secondaryScheme, o => o.Audience = "secondaryAudience");
            builder.Services.ConfigureAll<JwtBearerOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateTokenReplay = false,
                    SignatureValidator = (t, v) => new JwtSecurityToken(t)
                };
 
                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var claims = context.Principal!.Claims.Append(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Principal!.Identity!.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
                        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
 
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
            {
                const string policyName = "myPolicy";
                opts.AddPolicy(policyName, policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(defaultScheme, secondaryScheme);
                });
                opts.DefaultPolicy = opts.GetPolicy(policyName)!;
            });
 
            var app = builder.Build();
 
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapGet("/one", () => "hello").RequireAuthorization();
            app.MapGet("/two", () => "world").RequireAuthorization(a => a.RequireRole(roleName));
            app.MapGet("/info", (HttpRequest req) =>
            {
                var result = new StringBuilder();
                result.AppendFormat("User is in {0} role?: {1}", roleName, req.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(roleName));
                result.AppendLine();

                result.AppendFormat("User is authenticated?: {0}", req.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                result.AppendLine();
 
                var roleClaims = req.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);
                foreach (var roleClaim in roleClaims)
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("Role: {0}", roleClaim.Value);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }).RequireAuthorization();
 
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both schemes work in the same way when it comes to adding the `Administrator` role to inbound requests via the `OnTokenValidated` event.

### Steps to create demo project

1. Create a new empty ASP.NET 7.0 web API (using top-level statements, no HTTPS or Docker needed).
2. Add the following packages:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="6.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.11" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3. Paste the entire code above into Program.cs
4. Run it and make requests

### Endpoints

#### /info

If you make a request for `/info` with either JWT token, you'll see that the user the token represents does indeed have the Administrator role, that it's considered to be authenticated, and that is the only role.

The output looks like this:

```
User is in Administrator role?: True
User is authenticated?: True
Role: Administrator
```

#### /one

Either token will work (200 response) when it comes to making a request against `/one`, presumably because it doesn't require checking roles. You should get the result "hello" when calling it.

#### /two

`/two` requires the caller to have the role `Administrator`. The behaviour you'll observe is that it works for tokens belonging to the `DefaultScheme` scheme (200 response), but not for tokens belonging to the `SecondaryScheme` scheme (403 response).

But if you then change `DefaultAuthenticateScheme = SecondaryScheme`, the reverse will become true: `/two` will work for tokens belonging to `SecondaryScheme` (200 response), but not for tokens belonging to `DefaultScheme` (403 response). Herein lies the problem.

## Notes

1. The same problem occurs in the same way on non-minimal APIs decorated with the `[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attributes, but I used minimal APIs here to reduce the size of the example code.
2. I wondered if my code in `OnTokenValidated` was perhaps not actually working how I expect it to, but commenting the entire event out leads to the user of course not having `Administrator` or any roles when calling `/info`, and denies both tokens when calling `/two`, so clearly it is the part of the code that makes the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme`'s token successful when calling `/two`.
3. I'm not sure where the idea came from that these are Windows permissions, or OS permissions of any sort. The users are application level users, the permissions are application level permissions, intended to control access to certain functionalities within the API. Although my project is not using ASP.NET Core Identity, roles are based on having role claims against the authenticated user and, again, roles are part of application's domain (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users)) on how roles can be created for those who are using ASP.NET Core Identity to get a better idea of what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(original answer below)

Somehow I didn't think that `OnAuthenticationFailed` will be invoked even in case of normal auth flow - if you have several schemas - some will fail and one might succeed, so forcing auth of all available audiences obviously makes the second token to succeed for the first (default) schema (security issue).

Indeed, the root of the problem was the `.RequireAuthorization(a => { /*... */ })` call for the `/two` endpoint - auth policies are not simply combined but defined from scratch, so default policy was ignored completely. Passed delegate was missing an `AddAuthenticationSchemes` call, thus accepting the default scheme only.

---

**Original answer:**

If you set `JwtBearerEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed` handler, you will quickly discover the reason:

```
IDX10214: Audience validation failed.
Audiences: 'secondaryAudience'.
Did not match:
   validationParameters.ValidAudience:  'defaultAudience'
or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

setting both audiences in `TokenValidationParameters` should do the trick:

```cs
o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    /* ... */
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudiences = new[] { "defaultAudience", "secondaryAudience" },
    /* ... */
};
```

Why it is not populated by default? I don't know.

Also it seems like empty `.RequireAuthorization()` just requires auth processing, but does not require it to succeed (`/one` endpoint also fails to validate the token).
Changing to `.RequireAuthorization(a => a.RequireAuthenticatedUser())` will make `/one` fail just as `/two`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, in the real application, both tokens cannot be validated by the same handler, so this wouldn't be a solution for me. In the actual application, each token is provided by a different authority (one legacy and one new). While it would solve the problem of different audiences, it would introduce a problem of different signing keys, and the (potential) security issue of the legacy authority signing a token whose `aud` claim pretends to be the audience per the new authority, or vice versa.

Comment: `TokenValidationParameters` also accepts a custom `AudienceValidator` delegate, where you have access to token signing key and token audiences.

Comment: It seems like I need to find another solution altogether, since I'm currently using the `.Authority` parameter of the handler to point at the URLs respective IdentityServer implementations. I guess I would need to manually query both to get the signing keys, and then validate that, but also use the signing key that was used to validate the audience. It's weird that `.RequireAuthorization` seems to be ignoring my _default_ policy, which also requires an authenticated user. It's also weird that my code in `/info` states that the user is authenticated. So frustrating.

Comment: I honestly can't fathom why Microsoft have methods in the policy such as `AddAuthenticationSchemes` when only the  first scheme is ever going to work.

Comment: Hold on... adding `.AddAuthenticationSchemes(defaultScheme, secondaryScheme)` to the specific `.RequireAuthorization` for `/two` results in it working for both tokens. Is my policy honestly just being ignored?! 

Comment: OK. I've figured it out. In my real project, I'm using `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`. In this demo, I used minimal APIs so that it required less code, and `.RequireAuthorization` is helpfully documented with a message that I didn't notice: _"**Adds an new authorization policy** configured by a callback to the endpoint(s)."_. It seems that a new authorization policy, which doesn't accept both schemes, is used when a role verification is required. Your comment about adding `.RequireAuthorization` put me on the right track, so I'll award you with the bounty when the minimum time expires.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me find the source of my problems.

Comment: Updated answer with the final conclusion since original was kinda misleading at the start.